# Count Total Bar codes of Specific Color by fetching values from various fields when they match in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a situation where I have 4 color columns(Color1, Color2, Color3, Color4) I need to add the values of bar codes present in all color columns when they match. Its bit complicated, I have the graphical representation here:

```
Color1  Color2  Color3  Color4  Barcodes
  Red                              1
          Red                      3
                  Red              4
                          Red      2
```

Expected Result: **Total Barcodes where Color is Red=10**

I am using SQL Server

Any Assistance in this would be really helpful.

EDIT: there are 320 colors in the table

Answer (score 3):

I would unpivot and aggregate:

```
select sum(Barcodes)
from t cross apply
     (values (color1), (color2), (color3), (color4)) v(color)
where color = 'Red';
```

If you want this for each color:

```
select color, sum(Barcodes)
from t cross apply
     (values (color1), (color2), (color3), (color4)) v(color)
group by color;
```

Comment: But I have 320 colors..how do we handle that?

Comment: remove the where clause and as color to the select list with a group by